# Minimum passable audio quality for Google Speech API (and how to set)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-speech-api

I'm working with the Speech API and want to make it possible to configure the service for low bandwidth environments.

I notice audio quality settings are configured in two places in the sample code:

First in AudioEmitter.kt

```
fun start(
            encoding: Int = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            channel: Int = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            sampleRate: Int = 16000,
            subscriber: (ByteString) -> Unit
    )
```

And then in MainActivity.kt

```
if (isFirstRequest.getAndSet(false)) {
    builder.streamingConfig = StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
            .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                    .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                    .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                    .build())
            .setInterimResults(true)
            .setSingleUtterance(false)
            .build()
}
```

I have two questions:

First, what is the minimum recommended audio quality for the speech API? Has Google done research on different settings?

Second, the two samples set quality with different objects that don't necessarily line up. For example, `AudioFormat` contains both a `16BIT` and `8BIT` mode, while `RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding` only contains a `LINEAR16` option. And while `RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding` contains a `FLAC` option (which is recommended), turning `FLAC` on while leaving `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT` in place seems to break the stream.

How do I get this all to work together, and what are my best low bandwidth options?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the Google Speech API, but I record voice using android app for use in scientific analysis, and in our testing we have found that you can record in surprising low settings without losing the ability to preform complex analysis on the recording. Here is what we have settled on, for min bandwidth but still workable:

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64000);
```

Might not be perfect for you, but a good place to start. Good luck!

Comment: Do you get much background noise, or is it a quiet environment?

Comment: Totally depends, we use it in an app that is used in real life as people usually use their phones, so it totally varies.